# show full id shortened on button click -javascript-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can usage .slice method for cut a word. Here is example:

```
let UserID = 4EA1FC29-08D0-5A49-8754-DBD2691A0D36
let ShortUserID = UserID.slice(0, 14)

console.log(ShortUserID) here is console print: 4EA1FC29-08D0-
```

But my idea is click "..." button and open "selected row only" id.

[image]

Click a "..." button and show full id on just selected row(in this example clicking the button opens the id of all rows). My template is wrong. Here is my template:

[image]

Click button and show all ID's. Not "selected row". I want a click "..." button and show just selected row full id. I hope i could explain.

Here is my code template:

```
              let ShortUserID = UserID.slice(0, 14)

              const handleFullUserID = (index) => {
                setIsClicked(!isClicked) //True-False Operator
              }

              if (isClicked) {
                ShortUserID = UserID
              }
            
               return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>
                    {ShortUserID}(notfixed)
                    <button onClick={(index) => handleFullUserID(index)}>
                      ...
                    </button>
                  </td>
</tr>
)
```

Comment: Can you update the code to a runnable [mcve] so we can observe what you're describing, rather than referencing it in pictures?

Comment: Where do you declare `UserID`?

Comment: *"in this example clicking the button opens the id of all rows"* - The code shown has only one row.  **Usually** the behavior described indicates that the code has multiple records of some data but is using only one boolean state value to show/hide all of those records.  I **suspect** the code shown has been edited for brevity a bit too much and no longer demonstrates the problem.  This is why a [mcve] is important.  So we can understand the problem and correct it, rather than make random guesses which is all we have so far.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski @KonradLinkowski have a array list and UserID just one parameter in this array list. 

```
{filteredUsers.map((userDetail, index) => {
              const {
                UserID,
                Country,
                MMA,
                Time,
                Game,
                Revenue,
                Timezone,
                Device_Model,
                Ad_Type,
                Is_Gamepot,
                SubNetwork,
              } = userDetail
```

Comment: @David i reading your first answer and i need a time for understaning :) thx sir

Answer (score 0):

`{isClicked ? UserID : ShortUserID}`

Comment: still all lines open when i click a button. what i want is to open only the line with the clicked button.

Comment: You didn't mention anywhere in the question that all lines are opening.

Comment: This is probably a cleaner way to achieve the current functionality, but logically this doesn't do anything different than the `if` block that's currently just before the `return`.

Comment: OP wrote `my template is wrong` so I showed them how to do it properly. OP never said what is wrong

Comment: @KonradLinkowski sorry my english maybe littlebit bad :) the descriptions in the post have been updated again. Thanks for making me pay attention.